# RenderFlex overflowed only on screen transition but no visual issues

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

First, let me start with I am new to Flutter and this is my first app.

I am running into an issue where I am getting the error:

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by 24 pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Column
lib/widgets/home_screen_cta.dart:42
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

For the 4 buttons on my home screen.

The weird part is the screen looks fine. No yellow and black bars or anything. This only happens when I transition from the login screen to the home screen. If I move around the app, this does not happen. I do notice it on another form once it is submitted (only for the first submission, not for any others). It also looks bad for the first animation but after that it looks fine.

[image]

I was wondering if I should just ignore this but it seems like that is a bad idea.

I have tried changing this to use many other options. This includes:

- Changed between Expanded and Flexible
- Tried using a container/SizedBox instead
- Tried to find another solution for the CTA Item but couldn't find anything that would do this look

At this point, I understand it's a overflow issue but there are no indications of an overflow appearing in the app.

I am trying to make the app responsive in nature so I believe I am doing okay for that. This RenderFlex overflow issue is really puzzling. The fact I don't see the yellow/black bars in the app makes me think this is happening during a transition and I wonder if I should be concerned about it?

Is there a way to control these animations? I really do not like them and I feel it's the transition causing the overflow issue... I'm a bit lost on this.

My code:

**Home Screen (HomeDashboard):**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../app/components/app_drawer.dart';
import '../app/components/app_bar.dart';
import '../lang/app_localizations.dart';
import '../widgets/clock_text.dart';
import '../widgets/home_screen_cta.dart';
import '../widgets/home_screen_dashboard.dart';
import '../widgets/logo_horizontal.dart';

class HomeDashboard extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeDashboard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: FreshFlowAppBar.get(title: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.title),
      drawer: const AppDrawer(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: const [
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                fit: FlexFit.loose,
                child: LogoHorizontal(),
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                fit: FlexFit.loose,
                child: ClockText(),
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 6,
                fit: FlexFit.tight,
                child: HomeScreenDashboard(),
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                fit: FlexFit.tight,
                child: HomeScreenCta(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**HomeScreenCta:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_font_icons/flutter_font_icons.dart';
import 'package:fresh_flow/services/user.service.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../lang/app_localizations.dart';

import '../screens/home/pre_op_entry.dart';
import '../screens/home/prod_entry.dart';
import '../screens/home/post_op_entry.dart';
import '../screens/home/downtime_entry.dart';

import '../services/pre-op.service.dart';
import '../utils/size_helpers.dart';

class HomeScreenCta extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreenCta({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreenCta> createState() => _HomeScreenCtaState();
}

class _HomeScreenCtaState extends State<HomeScreenCta> {
  bool _isPreOpSetupCompleted = false;

  /// Returns a Widget for the CTA item
  Widget _getCtaItem(
    BuildContext context,
    String title,
    IconData iconData,
    String routeName,
    bool isEnabled,
  ) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (isEnabled) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(routeName);
        }
      },
      child: Opacity(
        opacity: isEnabled ? 1.0 : 0.4,
        child: Column( // This is causing RenderFlex overflow issue
          children: [
            Icon(
              iconData,
              size: displayHeight(context) * .05,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: displayHeight(context) * .03,
            ),
            Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: displayWidth(context) * 0.03,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final l10n = AppLocalizations.of(context);

    // Define services
    final _preOpService = Provider.of<PreOpService>(
      context,
      listen: false, // No need to listen
    );
    final _userService = Provider.of<UserService>(
      context,
      listen: false, // No need to listen
    );

    _preOpService.init(_userService.getId()!);
    // Only Pre-Op Entry is allowed until it is complete all others need to be disabled
    if (_preOpService.hasCompletedFirstPreopOfTheDay()) {
      setState(() {
        _isPreOpSetupCompleted = true;
      });
    }

    final _width =
        (displayWidth(context) - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.left) *
            0.24;

    final _children = [
      SizedBox(
        width: _width,
        child: _getCtaItem(
          context,
          l10n!.preOpEntry,
          FontAwesome.wrench,
          PreOpEntry.routeName,
          true,
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: _width,
        child: _getCtaItem(
          context,
          l10n.prodEntry,
          MaterialCommunityIcons.account_hard_hat,
          ProdEntry.routeName,
          _isPreOpSetupCompleted,
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: _width,
        child: _getCtaItem(
          context,
          l10n.postOpEntry,
          Icons.task_alt,
          PostOpEntry.routeName,
          _isPreOpSetupCompleted,
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: _width,
        child: _getCtaItem(
          context,
          l10n.downtimeEntry,
          Icons.flag_sharp,
          DowntimeEntry.routeName,
          _isPreOpSetupCompleted,
        ),
      ),
    ];

    return Center(
      child: Row(
        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: _children,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried SingleChildScrollView ? wrap your body and see if the error is gone ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too and I still get the same thing. Asides from that the buttons are left aligned, the RenderFlex overflow still happens

Comment: Have you tried to change the `displayHeight(context) * .05` to `displayHeight(context) * .03` or a fixed heigth?

Comment: I just tried with a fixed height. This is more unpredictable. It didn't happen the for the transition from login to the home dashboard but it did from another form submission to the home dashboard. The weird part, is that when I log out and back in again, it then shows the errors again. With the other form submission, it only happens on the first transition, which looks like crap anyways but then it's fine after that transition... Very strange

Comment: Now using the `SingleChildScrollView` with the fixed height, it no longer does it! Thanks to both of you(@AliYarKhan and @LuanSilva) for your help with this!

Comment: @Jeremy Welcome !!! Happy Fluttering !